# giving an ImageView circular bounds?

Tags: ios, uiimageview

I am using an `ImageView` to render a circular gradient for selecting a color.

The problem is, that as long as my `panGestureRecognizer` remains inside the **rectangular** `ImageView`, he will continue returning colors even when outside of the **circular** gradient.

Is there a way to enforce circular bounds?

Here is the code for adding the gradient into the `ImageView` :

```
CGSize size = CGSizeMake(self.view.bounds.size.width, ((self.view.bounds.size.height)/2));
UIGraphicsBeginImageContextWithOptions(CGSizeMake(size.width, size.height), YES, 0.0);
[[UIColor whiteColor] setFill];
UIRectFill(CGRectMake(0, 0,size.width,size.height));


int sectors = 180;
float radius = MIN(size.width, size.height)/2;
float angle = 2 * M_PI/sectors;
UIBezierPath *bezierPath;
for ( int i = 0; i < sectors; i++)
{
    CGPoint center = CGPointMake(((size.width)/2), ((size.height)/2));
    bezierPath = [UIBezierPath bezierPathWithArcCenter:center radius:radius startAngle:i * angle endAngle:(i + 1) * angle clockwise:YES];
    [bezierPath addLineToPoint:center];
    [bezierPath closePath];
    UIColor *color = [UIColor colorWithHue:((float)i)/sectors saturation:1. brightness:1. alpha:1];
    [color setFill];
    [color setStroke];
    [bezierPath fill];
    [bezierPath stroke];
}
img = UIGraphicsGetImageFromCurrentImageContext();
gradientView = [[UIImageView alloc]initWithImage:img];;
```

Comment: check the location of your pan. if it's outside of the imaginary circle don't return a color.

Comment: and how would one do that?

Answer (score 0):

you should check if your touch is inside of the imaginary circle.

All you need is pretty basic trigonometry. You need to calculate the distance between the touch point and the center of your view. If that distance is bigger than the radius of your colorView you want to return without changing to a new color (or set the value that is at the edge of the colorView)

I use something like this for a hue and saturation picker.

```
- (void)gestureRecognizerDidPan:(UIPanGestureRecognizer *)gesture {
    CGFloat saturation = 0.0f;
    CGFloat hue = 0.0f;

    UIView *colorView = gesture.view;
    CGPoint location = [gesture locationInView:colorView];

    // we assume that the colored area is a circle inside of a square rect
    CGPoint colorViewCenter = CGPointMake(ceilf(CGRectGetWidth(colorView.bounds)/2.0f), ceilf(CGRectGetHeight(colorView.bounds)/2.0f));
    CGFloat colorViewRadius = floorf(CGRectGetWidth(colorView.bounds)/2.0f);

    CGFloat dx = location.x - colorViewCenter.x;
    CGFloat dy = location.y - colorViewCenter.y;
    CGFloat touchRadius = sqrtf(powf(dx, 2)+powf(dy, 2));
    if (touchRadius > colorViewRadius) {
        // touch was outside of circular area

        // set saturation to max
        saturation = 1.0f;

        // or: 
        // return;
    }
    else {
        saturation = touchRadius / colorViewRadius;
    }

    CGFloat angleRad = atan2f(dx, dy);
    CGFloat angleDeg = (angleRad * (180.0f/M_PI) - 90);
    if (angleDeg < 0.f) {
        angleDeg += 360.f;
    }
    hue = angleDeg / 360.0f;

    // tell your target
}
```